# Making an output buffer return more readable/maintainable

Tags: perl, bash

I'm new to Perl, but I would like to make the following return more readable.
I have no choice but to maintain this old code.
I've read in places to never use both `qx` and `$_`

I was thinking of storing `$_` in a variable and returning that.
How come the last argument of the return gets executed? Its a strange concept to me (Java developer)

The script outputs the content of an sql query to command line and then parses it and performs various routines with it.

What would the guru's of stack overflow think of this ?

```
sub query_db {
    my $cmd = "cat /tmp/sql.$$ | db.sh -d ~~~ $db";  
    return map {chomp; $_;} qx/$cmd/;
}

foreach my $row (&query_db($sql, "database")) {
    blah
}
```

Comment: I would rewrite that return as `chomp(@cmd=qx/$cmd/);return @cmd;`

Answer (score 2):

You're fretting about the wrong things. Start by getting your program correct.

```
my $cmd = "cat /tmp/sql.$$ | db.sh -d ~~~ $db";
```

should bne

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );
my $cmd = "cat /tmp/sql.$$ | db.sh -d ~~~ ".shell_quote($db)";
```

and you might as well get rid of the wastefully useless use of `cat` while you're at it

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );
my $cmd = "db.sh -d ~~~ ".shell_quote($db)." </tmp/sql.$$";
```

Comment: :) sure - but instead `use ShellQuote;` need `use String::ShellQuote;`

Answer (score 1):

This is basically same as above,

```
sub query_db {
    my $cmd = "cat /tmp/sql.$$ | db.sh -d ~~~ $db";  
    my @out = qx/$cmd/;
    chomp(@out);
    return @out;
}

foreach my $row (query_db($sql, "database")) {
    blah
}
```

one that wrote original script didn't know that array can be chomped at once, so he used `map` to `chomp` line be line.

`&` in front of subroutine call is unnecessary, and other than that I wander why are parameters passed to `query_db` when subroutine doesn't use them.